# Get Number of plots on saved matlab figure automatically

Tags: matlab, plot, graphic, axes

Lets think we have a figure as;

```
figure(1),plot(1:10);hold on;plot(2:2:45)
```

and save this figure. When i open it as *.*fig format, i want to get information from figure(1) how many plots on it. There is 2 plots on figure1, but i would like to get this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a command like

```
numplots =  numel(get(gca,'Children'))
```

or if you are looking for how many lines :

```
numlines = numel(findobj(gcf,'Type','line'))
```

for example a function that does this could be:

```
function NumSons = sons_of_figure
[filename,pathname]=uigetfile('*.fig','Select File to Open');
        if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
            return
        else
            open(fullfile(pathname,filename));
            NumSons = numel(get(gca,'Children'));
        end
end
```

To change the color of a line you need to know (or find) its handle. In your example you can associate at each line a name:

```
figure(1),plot(1:10,'DisplayName','one');hold on;plot(2:2:45,'DisplayName','two')
```

Then you save and load the figure. If you want to change the color of the first line, named 'one', to red:

```
line1 = findobj(gcf,'DisplayName','one')%line1 is the handle to the line you want
set(line1,'color','r')
```

Comment: Thanks, so i want to ask next step: how can i indicate one of these lines. Etc; i have 3 line on my graphic and i want to change line color one of them. how can i write my "set(...)" command

Comment: You need to find the _handle_ of your line and then you can change the color. now i'm going to update the code to give you some examples

Comment: thanks for your useful advices. moreover, is it possible for random figures. is there any way to apply your style on all figures

Comment: If the object you want to modify has a particular property value(for example it is a line object, or its color is blue rather than yellow) you can get its handle with the findobj function used above. I say you need a filter to get the plot object you want, otherwise you can get all the handles of the line objects and then try to see which is the one you are looking for

Comment: i think, i will deal with like that: 1) i get number of lines on figure, 2) i try to change some small changes and control wheter i want. Thank you so much

Comment: try to plot a line, like a = plot(1:10) and then type get(a). You will find all the properties of a line object. You could find your way getting the object's XData and YData properties, or change color or marker. if you think i answered your question(s), check this question as answered, thanks.